# Показывать один элемент и скрывать остальные

Tags: jquery

есть 4 div блока внутри некий контент, надо по клику на 4 кнопки показывать соответствующий элемент и скрывать другие 3 соответственно

Comment: в чем заключается вопрос?

Comment: `onclick` + `if` + `.toggle()`

Comment: видимо речь про аналог jquery-ui аккордеона

Comment: Вопрос в том что есть 4 блока со слайдерами и к каждому слайдеру планировалось сделать свой новостной блок, при выборе (клик по ссылке) одной рубрики должен выводиться слайдер от этого блока, но при этом должны скрываться остальные

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант сделать подобным образом:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>titile</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <style>

 </style>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(function(){

   $('#divArea > div').hide();

   $('#inpArea').on('click', 'input', function() {
    $('#divArea > div').hide();
    var i = $(this).index();
    $('#divArea > div').eq(i).show();
   });

  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="inpArea">
 <input type="button" value="1">
 <input type="button" value="2">
 <input type="button" value="3">
 <input type="button" value="4">
</div>

<div id="divArea">
 <div>1. lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
 <div>2. lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem </div>
 <div>3. lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem </div>
 <div>4. lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Код не работает...

Comment: @ДмитрийЯковлев он рабочий в контексте пустой страницы, исправил.

Comment: О, вот так похоже то что надо :) Спасибо :))

Comment: Еще такой вопрос как сделать так чтобы по умолчанию был виден первый блок? Что-то не выходят каменные цветы у меня :(